# Crossfading image hides other elements

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make two images crossfade when you hover over them, and it works besides the fact that it hides the text I need. The text should be under the image instead of behind it. How can I fix this?

```css
#center {
  text-align: center;
}

#under {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#crossfade {
  position: relative;
}

#crossfade img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  margin-right: 3%;
  max-width: 65%
}

#goofy {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div id="crossfade">
    <img id="goofy" src="https://inpulse.eli328.repl.co/half.png" alt="half" class="bottom">
    <img id="goofy" src="https://inpulse.eli328.repl.co/active.png" alt="active" class="top">
  </div>
  <p id="under">
    The Inpulse creates a powerful electric charge that when reaching sufficient levels, creates a bright arc of lightining between the two prongs. The handheld device will definitely satisfy its user.
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give `#crossfade` width & height.

```css
#center {
  text-align: center;
}

#under {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 50%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#crossfade {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 330px;
}

#crossfade img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#crossfade img.top:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}

img {
  margin-right: 3%;
  max-width: 65%
}

#goofy {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div id="center">
  <div id="crossfade">
    <img id="goofy" src="https://inpulse.eli328.repl.co/half.png" alt="half" class="bottom">
    <img id="goofy" src="https://inpulse.eli328.repl.co/active.png" alt="active" class="top">
  </div>
  <p id="under">
    The Inpulse creates a powerful electric charge that when reaching sufficient levels, creates a bright arc of lightining between the two prongs. The handheld device will definitely satisfy its user.
  </p>
</div>
```